# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'float' and 'str' - Python/Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the two following lists:

```
list1=['21', '28', '28', '18', '17', '17', '18', '16', '20', '21', '22', '22', '20', '17', '23', '21', '20', '21', '21', '22', '22', '22', '21', '22', '21', '20', '21', '20', '22', '21', '24', '24', '23', '23', '23', '22', '22', '22', '23', '24', '22', '23', '24', '20', '22', '23', '24', '23', '24', '22', '25', '26', '22', '21', '21', '21', '21', '20', '21', '23', '23', '23', '24', '21', '26', '26', '27', '26', '26', '29', '27', '26', '25', '27', '27', '26', '26', '24', '24', '23', '26', '24', '26', '29', '29', '28', '27', '27', '26', '26', '26', '28', '25', '26', '26', '24', '25', '25', '26', '25', '25', '25', '26', '31', '25', '24', '24', '24', '24', '24', '25', '24', '22', '26', '27', '26', '27', '28', '25', '28', '27', '28', '27', '29', '28', '28', '29', '28', '28', '25', '27', '27', '27', '27', '27', '29', '31', '30', '28', '28', '27', '28', '28', '27', '26', '28', '27', '25', '27', '25', '27', '26', '26', '27', '28', '32', '28', '26', '27', '26', '25', '25', '26', '25', '26', '25', '27', '26', '26', '25', '28', '28', '29', '29', '31', '34', '33', '31', '32', '32', '30', '32', '32', '31', '32', '33', '35', '36', '37', '35', '35', '34', '33', '32', '32', '34', '32', '32', '32', '31', '32', '31', '33', '31', '33', '33', '34', '37', '32', '32', '32', '32', '32', '30', '34', '35', '33', '35', '34', '32', '36', '38', '38', '38', '37', '37', '38', '39', '37', '38', '38', '39', '39', '39', '38', '39', '38', '41', '39', '43', '44', '44', '45', '44', '42', '42', '44', '43', '41', '43', '43', '43', '40', '41', '39', '41', '39', '40', '40', '45', '42', '41', '40', '40', '41', '40', '42', '42', '38', '42', '44', '45', '45', '45', '44', '46', '48', '47', '50', '51', '50', '51', '49', '50', '48', '49', '50', '51', '50', '52', '53', '56', '57', '55', '54', '53', '55', '53', '54', '51', '53', '52', '51', '49', '48', '48', '49', '50', '47', '48', '51', '53', '53', '50', '47', '47', '48', '47', '48', '47', '49', '48', '52', '60', '58', '55', '100', '61', '55', '55', '54', '54', '54', '55', '55', '54', '53', '54', '53', '55', '56', '54', '55', '56', '58', '56', '56', '56', '55', '54', '55', '56', '56', '56', '56', '53', '54', '54', '54', '54', '52', '52', '54', '57', '58', '55', '54', '52', '52', '52', '54', '55', '54', '53', '53', '56', '57', '56', '56', '58', '55', '61', '59', '60', '61', '60', '64', '61', '62', '61', '60', '62', '63', '63', '65', '67', '69', '71', '68', '69', '66', '68', '70', '69', '69', '70', '69', '67', '68', '66', '65', '66', '63', '63', '64', '66', '72', '68', '65', '62', '64', '61', '63', '60', '59', '62', '63', '64', '65', '63', '61', '64', '63', '61', '61', '63', '64', '64', '63', '62', '65', '64', '64', '64', '64', '68', '66', '68', '69', '72', '70', '68', '66', '68', '65', '71', '69', '62', '63', '64', '61', '63', '64', '64', '64', '62', '60', '62', '70', '66', '65', '62', '62', '62', '62', '60', '64', '64', '64', '66', '66', '63', '69', '68', '66', '67', '69', '68', '67', '67', '68', '66', '68', '67', '68', '70', '71', '69', '70', '70', '75', '75', '73', '69', '71', '69', '69', '69', '73', '71', '71', '69', '67', '67', '65', '68', '69', '64', '66', '65', '70', '66', '66', '64', '63', '65', '64', '65', '66', '65', '65', '66', '68', '65', '65', '69', '66', '68', '65', '70', '69', '71', '69', '71', '72', '69', '68', '67', '68', '71', '72', '74', '76', '72', '71', '72', '70', '69', '67', '70', '70', '66', '66', '68', '67', '66', '67', '65', '74', '68', '67', '69', '69', '68', '69', '67', '67', '66', '64', '63', '66', '66', '66', '66', '66', '64', '62', '66', '66', '65', '66', '68', '70', '69', '68', '67', '67', '67', '64', '67', '66', '68', '66', '69', '68', '69', '69', '65', '66', '69', '68', '69', '66', '65', '65', '66', '66', '65', '66']
list2=['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '2', '2', '2', '2', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '4', '3', '3', '2', '2', '3', '2', '2', '3', '3', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '3', '2', '2', '2', '3', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '3', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '3', '2', '2', '3', '3', '2', '3', '4', '4', '3', '5', '4', '5', '3', '4', '4', '5', '4', '3', '4', '3', '5', '4', '4', '3', '3', '5', '4', '4', '3', '4', '4', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '4', '5', '4', '6', '5', '5', '6', '5', '5', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '5', '6', '8', '9', '9', '6', '8', '7', '6', '7', '8', '11', '10', '8', '12', '10', '9', '9', '10', '10', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '11', '12', '11', '9', '10', '14', '9', '11', '8', '8', '9', '9', '8', '9', '10', '7', '8', '8', '8', '9', '10', '9', '9', '11', '12', '12', '11', '12', '12', '12', '12', '11', '9', '11', '10', '10', '9', '11', '10', '10', '9', '9', '9', '10', '10', '10', '9', '9', '7', '8', '7', '8', '8', '11', '11', '10', '13', '11', '11', '12', '10', '11', '9', '17', '11', '12', '13', '15', '19', '25', '23', '27', '28', '29', '36', '36', '38', '33', '36', '30', '35', '35', '35', '30', '36', '33', '34', '34', '34', '33', '32', '36', '33', '43', '37', '33', '37', '35', '35', '36', '40', '34', '34', '30', '29', '32', '33', '34', '31', '31', '34', '36', '29', '25', '23', '21', '22', '23', '23', '22', '24', '23', '23', '26', '31', '28', '31', '35', '35', '32', '33', '27', '30', '32', '32', '32', '31', '34', '34', '43', '48', '53', '62', '63', '70', '62', '65', '67', '63', '60', '57', '62', '51', '54', '56', '58', '56', '58', '60', '71', '61', '55', '57', '57', '59', '50', '50', '44', '40', '37', '37', '36', '42', '40', '39', '40', '35', '38', '38', '36', '45', '47', '100', '69', '51', '47', '46', '48', '45', '41', '44', '42', '43', '44', '37', '41', '42', '42', '38', '36', '38', '40', '34', '34', '33', '36', '38', '36', '35', '36', '30', '34', '34', '29', '28', '26', '22', '19', '19', '47', '36', '24', '27', '27', '28', '27', '27', '21', '18', '18', '16', '14', '14', '14', '13', '12', '13', '15', '12', '12', '13', '11', '11', '10', '13', '11', '10', '11', '11', '10', '10', '10', '8', '9', '9', '8', '7', '7', '7', '7', '6', '7', '7', '8', '6', '7', '6', '6', '6', '5', '5', '6', '5', '5', '5', '6', '6', '6', '5', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '5', '6', '6', '6', '6', '5', '6', '7', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '5', '6', '6', '6', '5', '5', '5', '6', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '6', '5', '5', '4', '4', '5', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '5', '4', '5', '5', '4', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '4', '5', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '3', '3', '4', '4', '4', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '4', '3', '3', '3', '4', '3', '3', '3', '3', '4', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '4', '3', '3', '2', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '2']
```

I'm passing them through the following function:

```
def line_plot(list1,list2,datelist,labellist1="list1",labellist2="list2"):
"""
Plots a chart based on two different lists
:param list1: list 
:param list2: list
:param datelist: a list of dates
:return: a chart with both lists
"""
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

norm_list1=[float(i)/max(list1) for i in list1]
norm_list2=[float(i)/max(list2) for i in list2]

plt.plot(datelist,norm_list1,label=labellist1)
plt.plot(datelist,norm_list2,label=labellist2)
plt.xlabel("Date")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

I'm getting the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/santanna_santanna/PycharmProjects/APIGTrends/TrendVesting.py", line 670, in <module>
line_plot(list_of_lists[0],list_of_lists[1],datelist)
File "/Users/santanna_santanna/PycharmProjects/APIGTrends/TrendVesting.py", line 587, in line_plot
norm_list1=[float(i)/max(list1) for i in list1]
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'float' and 'str'
```

Any ideas on what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What don't you understand about the error message?

Comment: You are trying to to divide a float by string. 
float(i)/max(list1) => error

max(list1) will return a longest string from the list1.

Comment: @AJ That's already been pointed out in the answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You try to divide an integer by a string.

```
norm_list1=[float(i)/max(list1) for i in list1]
norm_list2=[float(i)/max(list2) for i in list2]
```

`max(list1)` will give the heighest string in the list, since your lists are made of strings. Why do you have strings in the list and not integers? Convert your list to int or float or use the code below

To solve the error and keep your strings (which is probably not what you want):

```
norm_list1=[float(i)/float(max(list1)) for i in list1]
norm_list2=[float(i)/float(max(list2)) for i in list2]
```

To just convert your lists to int or float and solve the error (probably what you want):

```
newlist1 = [float(i) for i in list1]
newlist2 = [float(i) for i in list2]
```

And use the new lists instead.

Comment: `float(max(list1))` won't give the correct maximum. `'2' > '12'`

Comment: I know, but maybe he wants that? I will add it to the answer though.

Comment: `max(list1)` doesn't return the longest string (all the strings are the same length in `list1`), it returns the highest string.

Comment: @Barmar ah yep true, lexio order. Thanks for pointing

Answer (score 1):

max from list of string integers returns also string, so you are trying to divide float and string.

```
>>> max(['333', '22222'])
'333'
```

Why? [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270680/how-does-python-compare-string-and-int)

```
>>> 2.0 / '3'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'float' and 'str'
```